# dynamic image path for lightgallery plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress

We have already added the code,but only thumb images are displaying.we want natural image path.
I have attached image reference,Please go through this

```html
 <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>"> 
          <?php if ($thumb || $images) { ?>
          <ul class="thumbnails" id="lightgallery" >
            <?php if ($thumb) { ?>

             <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 prdbimgImg img-responsive" data-responsive="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" data-src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" >
                    <a href="" id="zoom_01">
                        <img  class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo $popup; ?>">
                    </a>
                </li>
                 <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($images) { ?>
            <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
              <li class="image-additional img-responsive" data-responsive="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" data-src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" >
                    <a href="" data-id="zoom_01">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo $popup; ?>">
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <?php } ?>

        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're setting your thumbnail to data-src:

```
data-src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>"
```

According to the [docs](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html#attributes), `data-src` should contain the full image.

If the images are stored in `$images` and thumbnails in `$thumb` as you say, then this should do the trick:

```
<ul id="lightGallery" >
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) { ?>
    <li data-src="<?php echo $images[$i]; ?>" >
        <img src="<?php echo $thumb[$i]; ?>" />
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: according to loop condition,which path i need to give?

Comment: Can you show me the code where `$images` is created? I do know what you store inside $images, therefor I cannot know what the path of your full image is ;-)

Comment: $images we are storing images, and $thumb storing thumb images.

Comment: If we give $images in data-src, first image is repeating 3 times

Comment: I have sent reference link,Please check in mobile version only